# When running npm install getting npm ERR! code ERESOLVE - Unable to resolve dependency tree

Tags: reactjs, npm

I'm writing a simple Azure DevOps extension in typscript and having a lot of trouble installing the necessary packages in package.json.
**nodejs 18.16.0
npm 9.51**
Does this mean that React 18.2 is not compatible with azure-devops-ui 2.167.75 needs React version 16.8.1 to build successfully?

Any help would be appreciated

I've included both the error output and what I have in the package.json file

package.json

```
{
  "name": "single-select-control",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
    "azure-devops-extension-api": "^2.221.0",
    "azure-devops-extension-sdk": "^3.1.2",
    "azure-devops-extension-ui": "1.0.2",
    "azure-devops-ui": "^2.167.75",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.5",
    "react-select": "^5.7.3"
  },
  "description": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.5",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.6",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "eslint": "^8.43.0",
    "eslint-config-defaults": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.25.3",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3",
    "tfx-cli": "^0.15.0",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "vss-web-extension-sdk": "^5.141.0",
    "webpack": "^5.88.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.15.1"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "watch": "webpack --mode=development --watch",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --open --mode=development",
    "package": "tfx extension create --rev-version --manifest-globs vss-extension.json --no-prompt --json",
    "build": "webpack --mode=production"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Output when running npm install

```
    npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
    npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! While resolving: single-select-control@0.1.0
    npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
    npm ERR! node_modules/react
    npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
    npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.1" from azure-devops-ui@2.167.75
    npm ERR! node_modules/azure-devops-ui
    npm ERR!   azure-devops-ui@"^2.167.75" from the root project
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
    npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
    npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR!
    npm ERR! For a full report see:
    npm ERR! C:\Users\z070187\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-07-03T23_58_46_212Z-eresolve-report.txt
    
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\z070187\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-07-03T23_58_46_212Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: It seems that you are using create react app, which is quite old and always have been giving out these kinds of messages. Try using a vite template if that's a new app, or [you have this guide for migrating](https://cathalmacdonnacha.com/migrating-from-create-react-app-cra-to-vite)

Comment: However if you still want to use CRA you may try your luck with yarn since it doesnt check dependencies that strictly as npm

Comment: You might have a version mismatch between your npm/node version and one of the dependencies in your package.json file. Double-check that

Comment: @Mamo thanks, I figured that's the case.  Do you know of a convenient way to check which version of node/npm a given dependency is compatible with?

Comment: Hey @mangel, I will add it in an answer what I suggest for you to do, since it got a bit long.

Answer (score 1):

@mangel you can check [this tool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npmvet), I haven't used it before and I'm not sure if it would help in your case. But I propose to you to try double-check the recently added dependencies that might have started causing this error, but if you are not aware of that. Try the following in a dev environment:

- Try running `npm audit fix`, this could fix some dependencies but this is only in the case if they're outdated.
- Remove chunks of the dependencies and try to install, keep doing that until you short list or be able to find a specific dependency causing the error. (this would be faster than checking the proper version of each one from documentation)
- You can as well lookup what is the proper npm/node version for each dependency there, however, it will take a long time to do that.
- For future avoidance to this error, you might need to add a simple dependency log to your project, you'd suspect a dependency by looking at the recent added dependency from the log.

NOTE: Before following these steps, make sure you are in a separate dev environment to avoid any complications and delete both the `package-lock.json` file and the `node_modules` folder

Comment: Thanks! I was able to find out that the eslint and the azure-devops-api dependencies were the problem.  Didn't really  need either of them and it built fine.  Thanks for the help!